# Google Play In-app billing step-by-step

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

I've been fruitlessly trying to figure this out. What exactly is needed to set up in-app billing for my Android application. In particular, the whole **Google Wallet Merchant account** is confusing me.

So, if I'm getting this right, these are the steps:

> 1. Create Google Developer Account
> 2. Create Google Wallet Merchant Account on same account as Developer
> 3. Upload your .apk to Developer console
> 4. Add products you wish to sell
> 5. Program that stuff in your app
> 6. Upload new .apk to console, add test accounts.
> 7. Test your app's in-app billing.

However, I am uncertain as to how to setup Google Wallet Merchant. The **official documentation states the following**:

> 1. The Google Wallet Merchant Center account which you need to link to your Google Play Developer Console account can only be linked once
>      from within the Developer Console interface.
> 2. Important: Once accounts are linked, they cannot be removed, changed, or updated. If you need to do this, please know that you will
>      have to sign up for a new developer account by paying the fee of $25
>      USD.

Then what is the point of Google wallet merchant sandbox accounts? Is there a way for me to implement *in-app billing* and test it without having real merchant account?
Can someone with more experience explain to me how to prepare  one's merchant account for testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay I will try to best explain the process. I just published my first app. You need to setup a Google Developer Account. Then you should be able to setup a Google Wallet Merchant account from a link within your google developer account. Inside the developer console you will link it to your Google Wallet account. That part shouldn't be too difficult. Next setup a test in-app product or products. Then upload your apk to Alpha testing and publish it. Add a tester email account in your settings for in-app billing. Now the testing part. I recommend using the Android API Static in-app billing method first. It's quick and pretty simple, you can find it here http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html. Next you want to test the real work flow to make sure your app will respond and react correctly. Make sure you use a phone or device that has the tester's google account setup first or else you won't be able to complete a successful process with your developer google account. Follow the in-app Billing Demo game's code guidelines.

Comment: Thanks, I actually needed a bit more info on specifics of creating a Google Wallet Merchant account, but eventually I succeeded.